# What can you execute on visually selected text in vim?

Tags: python, vim, vi

What are the possible operations (with keyboard shortcuts) that you could execute on a visually selected text? For the simplicity consider this simple piece:

```
   a  b  cd  1  p
   a  b  cd  2  y
   a  b  cd  3  t
   a  b  cd  4  h
   a  b  cd  5  o
   a  b  cd  6  n
```

**One specific question**: is it possible to execute Python/shell commands/scripts on selections?

A couple more specific questions:

**1-)** How to in-place sort the python column?

**2-)** How to switch place of columns?

**3-)** How to increment values? (say. only the numbers greater than 3 in selection)

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do this correctly, you need to use *filters* and vim's *execution mode*.

A *filter* is any standard UNIX program (`sort`, `awk`, `grep`, `cut`, `paste`, `sed` ...) that can read from stdin and write to stdout.

Vim's *execution mode* lets you read in or replace text with the output of a program. If you make a visual selection (say, using `V` or `C-V`), and hit `:`, your command prompt will immediately be `:'<,'>`, which means "Apply whatever command follows to the lines included in the visual selection." At this point, you can write `!foo` to replace the text with the output of program *foo*.

For example, to sort the text by the python column, select it, hit `:`, and enter `!sort -k5`. The whole command will look like `:'<,'>!sort -k5` Running it will produce:

```
   a  b  cd  4  h
   a  b  cd  6  n
   a  b  cd  5  o
   a  b  cd  1  p
   a  b  cd  3  t
   a  b  cd  2  y
```

For the other two tasks, `awk` is your friend. A command like `:'<,'>!awk '{ print $1, $3, $2, $4, $5 }'` is will flip the second and third columns (but note that inter-column spacing is collapsed). To increment columns, try something like `:'<,'>!awk '{ sub($4, $4+1); print }'`.

Answer (score 5):

This question is extremely broad, but to start with look at [`:help visual-operators`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/visual.html#visual-operators).

Regarding the specific question, check out the plugin [EvalSelection.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=889), which evaluates source code selected in a visual region in your shell, Python, and several other interpreters. As a very simple example, if you have the following in your Vim buffer:

```
pwd
echo $SHELL
```

Select the first line and type `<Leader>esp`. Breaking it down:

`<Leader>e` is the default key command to invoke EvalSelection.vim. `s` specifies that you want to evaluate it using your shell. `p` specifies that you want to print the results to Vim's command line.

I get the following output when running the above command: `~/Desktop` with the first line selected. I get `/bin/zsh/` using the same command on the second line.

Comment: I have added 3 specific questions. Thanks for the links. I am looking for the subtle operations.

Comment: Could you post a simple usage example with EvalSelection plugin?

Comment: When I select the first line add do:
:'<,'><Leader>esp        
###only the <Leader>esp part typed

I get:
E488: Trailing characters

Comment: This is actually a bit different then what my original intention is. I want to be able to **operate on selections** (treating them as data not valid statements on a language.) In other words say I selected 1..6 and I want to sum this range by a command like python sum(). But I can't seem to do it. Not sure is there any native vim-python  alternative to :perldo